# The nginx_phpfpm container goes unhealth when running on ECS as task

Tags: docker, devops, amazon-ecs

Why is it really happening on AWS ECS? I have tested the docker image locally before pushing it to ECR. It works so smooth and is healthy.

Now, if I send the same image to ECR and run it as task, setting up the task definition in ECS. Its stopping and running back every time after few period of time.

The health status shows unhealthy. I am not using the ALB for health check but using the ***docker health check service built in with ECS***. I though it might be the command issue so tried all the options hinted by people online.

```
CMD-SHELL, curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

But nothing seems working here.

> What might be the exact cause the docker image running so well locally
>   does not run on ECS?

I even though, may be its not running on background so added this command on Entrypoint setting in task definition of ECS.

```
systemctl start nginx
```

Comment: Have you checked **container logs** ? check also if port 80 is open on **aws**

Comment: yes, the logs shows nginx is exited. but wondering why in ecs only when same nginx image works great locally . Regarding ports ,they are all open